# If I have a matrix $A$, find $b \in \Bbb R^4$ so $Ax=b$ has no solution

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

If I have a matrix $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 \\ 1 & 4 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$, find $b \in \Bbb R^4$ so that $Ax=b$ has no solution.

Comment: It's practically impossibe to understand what your $\;A\;$ is. Read and learn the easy directions to properly write mathematics in this site, and also add what have you done so far, lest your question runs the risk to be closed.

Comment: Sorry about this mess, I tried to make it better!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first $3$ rows $R_i$ of your matrix are linearly dependent: $6R_1 = 3 R_2 = 2 R_1$; and they are clearly linearly independent of the fourth row; hence the rank of your matrix is $2$. (Or, conversely, for the columns you find that $2C_2 = C_3$).

Now let us pick $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$ and $b = (b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)^T$. Then $Ax = b$ thranslates to
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 \\ 1 & 4 & 8 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}x_2 + 2x_3\\2x_2 + 4x_3\\3x_2 + 6x_3\\x_1 + 4x_2 + 8x_3\\\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\\b_4\end{pmatrix}.$$
One of the (many!) things you learn from this, is that
$$b_2 = 2x_2+4x_3 = 2(x_2 + 2x_3) = 2b_1.$$
In other words: for a solution $x$ to exist, $b$ must be such that $b_2 = 2b_1$. So if you pick any vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^4$ with $b_2 \neq 2b_1$, no solution will exist.

Comment: Sorry, but "Hence the rank... is 2" is not a correct deduction at that stage.

Comment: @JeanMarie You're right, I forgot to mention the linear independence w.r.t the fourth row. Edited.